# Page width issues - all content gets pushed miles to the right when I want it to start directly under my header

Tags: html, css

My website is http://www.danidolldesigns.com/

My content seems to be getting pushed right over to the right causing my site to have a horizontal scroll which I do not want.I can't find how to set the width of the site so content starts from the very left with an small indent and all content to sit directly under the header image with no horizontal scroll..I've been through the code but I just can't see whats wrong. Feel free to inspect my code on my site ...any response is really appreciated .. thank you

Comment: oh and i have left a line of text live on my site so you can see what I mean.

Comment: Provide code and a specific question please.

Comment: Question seems clear enough. And how can you provide code when the issue is unknown. There are elements with fixed dimenions interfering with the responsive design. One is `.container` inside `footer` with 900px width (this one is inside a media query) and the other is `<a class="logo">` that gets it's width dynamically set to 960px. Try using developer tools and hovering over the element, scroll to the right and you will see which element is sticking out.

Comment: You should give a link that works (https gives a 404 page).  Second, provide the code on here so we can see it rather than linking to your site.  SO is meant to help future readers as well and a link to your site won't help anyone.

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it

Comment: @Shikkediel see link above.

Comment: Cheers, I'll keep that in mind. I feel we should give newbies a chance though and not immediately downvote.

Comment: The link works fine. I only asked for help because I haven't got a clue and I can't give code without giving you the entire sites code because I didn't know what was wrong. People on here are so snappy and ready to moan about my questions :/ I posted this question because I need help and I just get told I'm doing it wrong :/

Answer (score 0):

it is happening because of anchor tag under ".wrapper .container" div.
This anchor include the following css which make your content to goes over the container.

```
 position: absolute;
 TOP: 230px;
 LEFT: 64%;
```

So just remove these properties from your anchor or remove this anchor if you don't need it. And give "text-align:center;" to .wrapper class to let the content align center under header.